# Increase the number by one in PHP from array of IP addresses

Tags: php, arrays, math

I want to add to every IP address from array +1 number. I know about `bcadd();` but I can't make it work as every IP address has different length and I just need to increase the last number of it.

For example:

```
array("194.32.14.152", "4.189.23.35", etc...);
```

... would become:

```
array("194.32.14.153", "4.189.23.36", etc...);
```

Now maybe I need to apply `str_pad();` to match the last dot?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what would happen to an IP which looks like `"194.32.14.159"` ?

Comment: It would go `"194.32.14.160"` and so on, it doesn't matter as every number from last part should be just increased by +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your array to your new IP addresses. In the `map` method, you can split the current string by `.` using `explode()`. Then, to get the last number from your IP you can use `array_pop`, which you can then cast to an integer so that you can add one to it. You can then `array_push()` this updated value onto your parts array, and join each part in your array back together using `implode()`.

See example below:

```
$arr = array("194.32.14.152", "4.189.23.35", "4.189.23.255");

$res = array_map(function($v) { // Example, let $v = "194.32.14.152";
  $parts = explode('.', $v); // "194.32.14.152" -> ["194", "32", "14", "152"];
  array_push($parts, min((int) array_pop($parts)+1, 255)); // ["194", "32", "14", 153]
  return implode('.', $parts); // "194.32.14.153"
}, $arr);

print_r($res); // ["194.32.14.153", "4.189.23.36", "4.189.23.255"]
```

Comment: What happens if you have 192.32.14.255 and do a plus 1?

Comment: @MarkusZeller at the moment, it will become `... .256`, but you bring up a good point. I'll see if OP wants this case to be managed when they see the answer

Comment: I would suggest to handle that case. Else the answer is totally wrong, even if it works.

Comment: This actually works pretty good @Nick Parsons thank you for this approach, going to study this method and learn more how you did this.

Comment: @Newbie are you concerned about IPs going over the limit of `255` ? (eg: 192.32.14.256 technically isn't valid)

Comment: I guess there's no problem about it, but just to learn more how would we limit it to 255?

Comment: @Newbie it would depend on what you want to happen when the IP exceeds `.255`, for instance, should it remain the same IP, or would it increase the next part of the IP

Comment: It shouldn't change the number then if it's `.255`

Comment: @Newbie I've edited my answer so that it maintains the same IP if it ends with `.255`. To do this, we can get the minimum number between `255` and our newly computed number. If our new number is bigger than `255`, it will use `255` by default. If you want `255`+ to go to `0` you could use `((int) array_pop($parts)+1) % 256` as the push value instead

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace_callback()`, IMO, is the most succinct and appropriate approach.  When there is a single, native function that does it all, why do anything else?

Match the final sequence of digits and so long as it is not `255`, increment the substring.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/m3Qud))

```
$ips = ["194.32.14.199", "4.189.23.35", "4.189.23.255"];

var_export(preg_replace_callback('~\d+$(?<!255)~',
             function($m) {
                 return ++$m[0];
             },
             $ips)
          );
```

From PHP7.4+, the syntax becomes more brief by way of arrow syntax.

```
var_export(preg_replace_callback('~\d+$(?<!255)~', fn($m) => ++$m[0], $ips));
```

Both snippets produce:

```
array (
  0 => '194.32.14.200',
  1 => '4.189.23.36',
  2 => '4.189.23.255',
)
```

The pattern:

```
\d+        #match 1 or more digits
$          #match the end of the string
(?<!255)   #lookbehind to ensure the matched number is not literally 255
```

In using this pattern, you do not bother handling `255`, and you increment all other numbers that are matched.

Comment: @Newbie this is a cleaner way.  It you require further explanation, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for this method. Sadly I still didn't learn preg_replace syntax so the first solution seems more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using built-in [ip2long](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and [long2ip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) and PHP [bitwise operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
<?php

$ips = array("194.32.14.152", "4.189.23.35", "4.51.11.255");
$newIps = [];
foreach($ips as $ipString){
    $ip = ip2long($ipString);
    $lastByte = ($ip & 0x000000FF)+1;
    $lastByte = $lastByte > 255 ? 255 : $lastByte;
    $newIps[]= long2ip(( $lastByte ) | (0xFFFFFF00 & $ip ) );
}
var_dump($newIps);
```

This outputs

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "194.32.14.153"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "4.189.23.36"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "4.51.11.255"
}
```

Live demo https://3v4l.org/iZeAR

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks. I wanted to extend it to IPv6 but there is no `ip2long` and `long2ip` for IPv6 :(